# Can't get strtol() to detect overflow

Tags: c, overflow, detection, strtol

This program uses a lexical scanner to classify tokens as symbol, string, decimal number, hex number,… When a "number" is detected, it is handed over to `strtol()` to convert it to the internal 32-bit binary value. However I can't get `strtol()` to reliably return error on overflow.

Part of conversion code is:

```
    errno = 0;      // erase any previous error in errno
    switch (constType) {
…
case lxHex:         // hexadecimal number X'1234567890ABCDEF' (X-string)
fprintf(stderr,"** FindConstantFromString - converting %s\n",constBuffer);
        newDictEntry->dcValue = strtol(constBuffer+2, NULL, 16);
int myerr = errno;
fprintf(stderr,"     value %x errno %d\n",newDictEntry->dcValue, myerr);
        newDictEntry->dcType = syNumber;
        newDictEntry->dcSubType = 4;    // hexadecimal
        if  (   EINVAL == errno
            ||  ERANGE == errno
            ) {
            ErrDict = newDictEntry;
            AnaError (ConstMsg+2);
            newDictEntry->dcType = sySLit;
        };
        result.cstClass = newDictEntry->dcType;
        return result;
…
```

When this code is tested with wrong input, it detects overflow only if the first hex digit is >= 8 (potentially giving negative value), as remonstrated by:

```
    29            | declare v;
    30            | v = x'fedcba9876543210'
** FindConstantFromString - meeting x'fedcba9876543210' as 11
** FindConstantFromString - converting x'fedcba9876543210'
     value ffffffff errno 34
*Error 32: Candidate number x'fedcba9876543210' too large or could not be converted
*Error 20: Unrecognisable lexical unit x'fedcba9876543210' at 30.5
    31            |     + x'123456789abcdef'
** FindConstantFromString - meeting x'123456789abcdef' as 11
** FindConstantFromString - converting x'123456789abcdef'
     value 89abcdef errno 0
    32            |     + 9876543210
** FindConstantFromString - meeting x'fedcba9876543210' as 8
                            symbol already known
** FindConstantFromString - converting x'fedcba9876543210'
     value 0 errno 0
*Error 32: Candidate number x'fedcba9876543210' too large or could not be converted
** FindConstantFromString - meeting 9876543210 as 8
** FindConstantFromString - converting 9876543210
     value 4cb016ea errno 0
    33            |     + '12345a'
** FindConstantFromString - meeting 12345a as 3
    34            |     + '';
** FindConstantFromString - meeting 12345a as 8
                            symbol already known
** FindConstantFromString - converting 12345a
     value 3039 errno 0
*Error 32: Candidate number 12345a too large or could not be converted
** FindConstantFromString - meeting  as 3
** FindConstantFromString - meeting  as 8
                            symbol already known
*Error 33: Empty string cannot be converted to number
```

At line 30, the lexical scanner recognized a hex number and requested conversion from this hex form (11 = lxHex). `strtol()` correctly sets `errno` to `ERANGE` and error message is issued. Overflowed hex number is then kept in the dictionary as a string.

*Note that the returned value is -1, not `LONG_MAX`.*

At line 31, we again have another overflowing hex number, but it does not start with 8-9a-f. It is again detected as an hex number. Conversion is attempted but errno is not set at all. The value correspond to the lower 32 bits of the number. Since this considered success, the truncated value is kept as the result.

When `+` is applied to "x'fed…'" and 89abcdef, another conversion is attempted on the **string** "x'fed…'" supposed to be a decimal number (denoted by the 8-request) and conversion fails because "x" cannot begin a decimal number.

At line 32, we have an overflowing decimal 987654321. Once again, overflow is not detected (code not shown but similar to the one for hex numbers with the addition of a test on "endptr" since the strings may not be filtered by the lexical scanner and contain illegal characters). The returned value contains the least 32 bits of the number.

If I change `strtol()` to `strtoul()`, the first `ERANGE` error disappears and I get the least 32 bits of the number.

What am I doing wrong?

System: Fedora Linux 29
glibc: 2.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtol()` derives a `long` (i.e. a `signed long`) value from the given string.  It only cares about overflows or underflows of the 64-bit `long` value that it constructs internally, and that it will eventually return to its caller if no problems are encountered.  It does not care at all about overflows or underflows of 32-bit values.

This is why `strtol()` only returns an error in the examples you show where the `long` value would have overflowed into a negative 64-bit number.  (And as you noted, `strtoul()` does not complain in that case because there is no overflow of an `unsigned long` value in that case.  You would need to feed `strtoul()` a 17-digit string to overflow an `unsigned long`.)

`strtol()` also does not know or care that your program will take its 64-bit `long` result and immediately discard its upper 4 bytes by assigning the value to a 32-bit variable.  This truncation is why you were led to think that "*the returned value is -1, not `LONG_MAX`*".  In fact the result from `strtol()` **was** `LONG_MAX`, but your program has discarded the top 4 bytes of `LONG_MAX` and is left with only the low 4 bytes, whose value is `0xffffffff` or `-1` when treated as a 32-bit `int`.

If you want to use `strtol()` to generate and vet 32-bit values then you'll have to do additional range checking yourself.  After first collecting the `strtol()` result into a `long` variable and checking whether that result indicates a 64-bit overflow or underflow during the execution of `strtol()`, you can then compare that `long` result against `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` to see whether its value would overflow or underflow a 32-bit variable.

Obviously you can wrap this up in a little function, which could (if you do the appropriate tinkering with `errno`) behave just like `strtol()` except that it applies to `int` values rather than `long`.  However, you should resist the urge to give your function the name `strtoi` because names that begin with `str[a-z]` are reserved by POSIX for future use in the standard library.  Some systems might already have a `strtoi` and Linux might get one someday.

Comment: Biting my fingers! My misconception was to assume long == 32 bits with implicit equivalence of int == long int. I should have printed sizeof(long) to see my mistake. When you're tired, you don't see the obvious. *man limits.h* was not very helpful because it says *Long_MAX* acceptable value is 2^32-1 and I disregarded word **minimum** in the comments.

Comment: In C++ there's already the standard `std::stoi`. A small wrapper can be made for C if necessary